# Edit item in Jlist

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlist

How can I edit an item from a Jlist by simply adding an integer after that specific item (something like an append) ? Adding items to jlist with addbuttonlistener work fine but I don't know how can I edit them .

Comment: Didn't get your question. Can you elaborate it?

Comment: I want to append for an existing item in a Jlist an integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to use a `JTable` with a single column. Then you can use a CellEditor. See more about `JTable` and CellEditors on [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender).

Answer (score 2):

You have to update the [model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can used

```
 int x = txtList.getSelectedIndex();
    if (x >= 0) {
        listModel.remove(x);
        txtList.setModel(listModel);
    }
```

txtlist is your jlist name.
First, you should declare listmodel. if have problem , you can contact me to discus